# Regular expression to find config files used in transforms

Tags: regex

I need a solid working regex to get only those config files that I am using to transform my config.

The files will be looking like this:

### Normal Configs

- web.config
- connectionstrings.config
- anotherconfigfile.config

### Transform Configs

- web.test.config
- connectionstrings.test.config
- anotherconfigfile.test.config

The regex should only match the transform configs. I already tried something like `"^*.*.config$"` but this will select any config even if it's a (normal) web.config.

It shouldn't be hard I guess, but I'm not the strongest one on regular expressions.

**EDIT:** A solution in which I have to specify the word "test" in a regex won't be sufficient.

The variable which now is "test" could also be "accept" or "release" or "debug" or any other variable. It should therefor basicly pick up all the configs that have a Somename.SomeVariable.config structure.

### For example:

- something.test.config -> Should be matched
- something2.accept.config -> Should be matched
- something.release.config -> Should be matched
- web.config -> Should not be matched
- connectionstrings.config -> Should not be matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\w` to match all the word characters.

```
^\w+\.\w+\.config$
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a simple solution:

```
^\w+\.\w+\.config$
```

Answer (score 2):

A PERL compatible regex:

```
^([ \w]+\.)(?1)config
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH0bP3/1)**

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.config$).*$
```

You can use a `lookahead here to force your match to files ending`test.config`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lI0qN9/4

or

simply

```
^[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.config$
```

Comment: @Younes try now the edted one

Comment: Your regex matches `connectionstrings.t.e.st.config` too. Which is wrong.

Comment: Yes for now and I wonder why you're using lookahead really. Why not just `^[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.config$` alone?